# integral of holomorphic on the open unit disk and continuous on the closure is zero

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

If $f$ is holomorphic on the open unit disk and continuous on the closure then how to show that

$\int_{\gamma} z^k f(z)dz =0 $ for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$, where $\gamma$ is the unit circle curve.

I think this is straightforward from Cauchy's theorem as the integrand is holomorphic on the unit disk.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, the unit circle curve, I updated the question.

Comment: I think it is almost straightforward from Cauchy's theorem. Use Cauchy for circle with radius $r(<1)$, and tend $r \to 1$. Limiting process is justified because of uniform continuity of $z^k f(z)$.

Comment: What @sansae said. Most versions of CT talk about $f$ holomorphic in an open set $U$ and a curve $\gamma\subset U$; since here $\gamma$ is not contained in the open unit disk these theorems do not apply"directly".